# Increasing the maxPods of a k8s node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to dynamically increase the maxPods of a k8s node.  Currently its set to 30 and I want to increase it to 50. I'm following these instructions: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/

On the node I added the `--dynamic-config-dir` flag and restarted `kubelet`

I then added a configmap with maxPods set to 50 and added a configSource section to the node:

```sh
configSource:
    configMap:
        name: my-node-name
        namespace: kube-system
        kubeletConfigKey: kubelet
```

And I can verify the configmap has been applied via:

```sh
kubectl get no ${NODE_NAME} -o json | jq '.status.config'
{
  "active": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "my-node-config-c87h9fm782",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "54483288",
      "uid": "144bd26f-d290-11ea-bb9d-5e7d8d22eed0"
    }
  },
  "assigned": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "my-node-config-c87h9fm782",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "54483288",
      "uid": "144bd26f-d290-11ea-bb9d-5e7d8d22eed0"
    }
  },
  "lastKnownGood": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "my-node-config-c87h9fm782",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "54483288",
      "uid": "144bd26f-d290-11ea-bb9d-5e7d8d22eed0"
    }
  }
}
```

But the node is still only running 30 pods and any attempt to deploy another pod fails with the pod in the Pending state.

I pulled down the configmap and I verified maxPods is set to 50.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciate

Thanks,

Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify maxPods when creating new node pools, you receive a default value of 30 for Azure CNI

You're able to configure the maximum number of pods per node at cluster deployment time or as you add new node pools. If you deploy with the Azure CLI or with a Resource Manager template, you can set the maximum pods per node value as high as 250.

You can change via Azure CLI - Specify the --max-pods argument when you deploy a cluster with the az aks create command. The maximum value is 250.

You can't change the maximum number of pods per node when you deploy a cluster with the Azure portal.

Please read here how to change the value in existing cluster

[Reference Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni#configure-maximum---existing-clusters)

Comment: Thank you for the link.  This is exactly what i was looking for.  Cheer!

Answer (score 7):

**Default Max POD Value per node is 110**

```
ubuntu@k8s-master-1:~$ kubectl describe nodes k8s-worker-1  | grep -i "Capacity\|Allocatable" -A 6
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  12131484Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4046184Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  11180375636
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             3943784Ki
  pods:               110
```

**Find config file path for kubelet on worker node**

```
ubuntu@k8s-worker-1:~$ ps -ef | grep -i kubelet
ubuntu    5077  5005  0 20:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i kubelet
root     23930     1  1 06:42 ?        00:15:18 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=systemd --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
```

**Update/Add maxPods field on `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` as needed and restart kubelet on worker node**

```
ubuntu@k8s-worker-1:~$ sudo cat /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
cpuManagerReconcilePeriod: 0s
evictionPressureTransitionPeriod: 0s
fileCheckFrequency: 0s
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
httpCheckFrequency: 0s
imageMinimumGCAge: 0s
kind: KubeletConfiguration
nodeStatusReportFrequency: 0s
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: 0s
rotateCertificates: true
runtimeRequestTimeout: 0s
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 0s
syncFrequency: 0s
volumeStatsAggPeriod: 0s
maxPods: 500
```

**Verify pods value should be now changed after kubelet is restarted**.

```
ubuntu@k8s-master-1:~$ kubectl describe nodes k8s-worker-1  | grep -i "Capacity\|Allocatable" -A 6
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  12131484Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4046184Ki
  pods:               500
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  12131484Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             3943784Ki
  pods:               500
```

Comment: I should say I'm using Azure Kubernetes Services which defaults to 30 pods, Vanilla k8s defaults to 100.  The way you are doing it will work, but i was hoping to have a configmap that all my nodes will uses, so when i scale out nodes they will pick up the new configmap.  But modifing the kubelet command line args is definitely an option.